# This code shouldnt have an error. I cant figure out why this doesnt work

Tags: c#

My coding teacher gave me homework to build b a working code.
So i did and when i ran it it said there was an error. I couldn't find one and neither could my teachet. So my mom recommended to ask here to see if maybe we messed something. Sorry if i have spelling mistakes i am still learning English. P.s. i am learning the language c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Dcoder
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sibling1; 
            string sibling2;
            int age_sibling1; 
            int age_sibling2;
            Console.WriteLine( " insert your name and your age " );
            sibling1 = string Console.ReadLine();
            age_sibling1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine( " insert your sibrlings name and age " );
            sibling2 = string Console.ReadLine();
            age_sibling2 = int.Parse(console.ReadLine());         
            if (age_sibling1 > age_sibling2);
            Console.WriteLine(sibling1 + " is bigger " );
            Else;
            if (age_sibling2 > age_sibling1);
            Console.WriteLine(sibling2 + " is bigger " );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error? Where is it? What does it say?

Comment: One error is near your `if` you do not need a semicolon in `if (...);`. Next is `Else` c# is case sensitive, should be `else` and again - no semicolon!

Comment: also you should remove `string` from `string Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment and a learning exercise, you should really be learning how to fix these errors yourself (even though some have already done it for you). Take a look at [this link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2yMpNv), it shows you exactly where the errors are. From there, you should take a look at what you're trying to do, and then research how to actually do it (e.g. [Console.WriteLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [if-else](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else))

Comment: fixed code formatting and removed extra code comments

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Right now this can't be your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Made some changes to your code. Some suggestions: Int.Parse will throw an exception if user doesnt enter a number. I would suggest using try/catch
or [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Another thing is if you are using variable1, variable2, variable3 etc. its time to create a method and avoid using variableN.

```
string sibling1, sibling2;
        int age_sibling1, age_sibling2;
        Console.WriteLine("Insert sibling 1 name ");

        sibling1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Insert sibling 1 age ");

        age_sibling1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Insert sibling 2 name ");

        sibling2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Insert sibling 2 age ");

        age_sibling2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (age_sibling1 > age_sibling2)
            Console.WriteLine($"{sibling1} is bigger ");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"{sibling2} is bigger ");

        // Wait for user.
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am going to try these answers soon today.